# Ubuntu partition won't extend?

Tags: partitioning

I booted into a live USB and ran GParted but it wouldn't let me resize the main Ubuntu partition to use 10GB of unallocated space, I also have Windows 10 installed on the hard drive which I shrank to get the unallocated space?

Comment: When you say main ubuntu partition - what do you mean? Is it root(/). Whenever you are using gparted one need to unmount the partition on which they are trying to do the resize operation...root(/) cannot be unmounted within ubuntu session for gparted to do so.

Comment: Hard to say. Make sure swap is not mounted and the free space is adjacent to the partition you want to enlarge. Post a screen shot of gparted.

Comment: It is the root(/) partition I am trying to extend.

Comment: The swap was not mounted as well i unmounted it in the live USB.

Comment: @Ashu, gparted has been able to grow the root partition without unmounting it for a few years now.

Comment: @psusi. Is it? Is it possible even if somebody has only two partition root(/) and swap? Can we extend / even in that case without unmounting?

Comment: Post a screenshot of gparted.

Comment: It lets me extend all the other partitions (Windows C and the swap partition) but when I try to extend the root(/) partition it won't use the unallocated space? Also I would post a screenshot but I'm not sure how?

Comment: @Ashu, yep... and if you are using btrfs, it is even possible to *shrink* it while it is mounted.

Comment: So what can I do?

Comment: I needed to move the unallocated space to the other side of the Linux-swap partition and beside the (/) partition to extend it, thank for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You only can repartition unallocated space to the Ubuntu partition if it's immediately adjacent to that partition. Is that the case?

All answers about partitioning you also can find in a clear guide from GParted.
http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions

Answer (score 0):

You have to unmount the partition you want to extend. If it is the root partition, then you have to boot from another drive—a bootable USB stick, for example. To get one:

1. find out which `/dev/sd(letter)` is your stick by `sudo blkid`—you
   will be able to recognise the stick by label, UUID, type, or simply
   by observing which device appeared after you had inserted the stick,
2. get an Ubuntu image and put it to the USB stick (destroying all its
   previous content): i.e. `wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso -q -O -| dd of=/dev/sd(the letter) bs=4M`,
3. reboot,
4. enter BIOS and make sure you that your USB stick is boot priority,
5. boot from that stick,
6. choose 'Try Ubuntu' without installing,
7. run gparted.

Comment: I did boot from a USB stick and open GParted but it still won't let me extend the partition